# Specify sheet in private sub calculate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of sheets all duplicated from a master, each with a copy of some worksheet calculate code in the private sub for each sheet. 
However the code needs to reference the sheet it is in - therefore it cannot just be copied from the master.

I have placed the sheet code number on each sheet when it is created in cell B2.

My question is - how do I specify the sheet individually for 'with sheets(thissheet)'? I have tried pointing it at cell B2 but because it does not yet know which B2 it throws an error.

Is there a way to tell a private sub to use the sheet it is in as 'with..'?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `Target.Parent`? If you are using the [Worksheet Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) the you get `Target` along with it. Target is the cell (or the cells) which got changed on that sheet. The parent of that cell is the sheet on which the cell is hosted. So, `Target.Parent.Name` will give you the name of the sheet on which the cell is hosted. Is that what you want?

Comment: When you place your code in the code-module of a worksheet it systematically references this worksheet. `Me` is the keyword to specify that *"I am referring to the WS holding this piece of code"*. Me.range(...)`, `With Me` etc..?

Comment: Both great thanks. I've gone with Me for simplicity. Thanks again